# componentDidMount not changing state for array variable but it works if changed to int instead of array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
//import { collapseTextChangeRangesAcrossMultipleVersions, ImportsNotUsedAsValues } from 'typescript';
class App extends Component {
   state = {
    values: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
   
    //console.log("Component will mount called");
    this.setState({ values: [{id:1, name:'Value 101'}] });
    //console.log(this.state.values);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          Test
          <ul>
            {this.state.values.map((value:any)=>{
              <li>{value.name}</li>
            })}
          </ul>
          
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to create sample react ts application. While I try to set new values in componentDidMount the values are not changing. The behavior is same in componentWillMount, the state is not changing for values.

Comment: your problem in rendering, it must be like this
this.state.values.map((value:any)=>({
              <li>{value.name}</li>
            }))

Comment: After adding return resolved the issue. <ul>
            {this.state.values.map((value:any)=>{
              return (<li>{value.name}</li>)
            })}
          </ul>

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillMount` doesn't trigger rendering, [as stated in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount).

However, [you can change state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) in `componentDidMount`, which will result in rendering your component twice.

Moreover, you should probably replace

```js
{this.state.values.map((value:any)=>{
    <li>{value.name}</li>
})}
```

with

```js
{
    this.state.values.map((value: any, index: number) => {
        return <li key={index}>{value.name}</li>)
    }
}
```

as your current piece of code doesn't return a JSX object. Finally, try to use a real `key` instead of `index`.

Comment: componentDidMount is not changing state so I was trying componentWillMount.

Comment: `componentDidMount` can update your state, so I guess you are using it wrong. Did you update your code as indicated? For now, your `map` function doesn't return anything, hence the need to change it.

Comment: Yes After returning li in map it started working. Thanks....

Comment: Great! Consider accepting the answer then :)